# Retornar Post Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Eu tenho o seguinte script que me retorna o estado e a quantidade de posts que tem neste estado, agora eu gostaria de exibir estes posts, alguém conhece alguma solução?

```
<?php

    $query="
    SELECT 
        e.id ID,e.uf UF, e.nome Estado, COUNT( 1 ) Quantidade
    FROM 
        wp_treasuremap_posts p, wp_treasuremap_postmeta m, wp_treasuremap_localizacao_cidade c, wp_treasuremap_localizacao_estado e
    WHERE 
        p.id = m.post_id
        AND post_type =  'denuncia'
        AND meta_key =  'estado_e_cidade'
        AND post_status !=  'trash'
        AND meta_value = c.id
        AND c.estado = e.id
    GROUP BY 
        e.uf, e.nome
    ORDER BY 
        3 DESC ";

    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $tot=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $c=0;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){

    $ID=$row->ID;

    $Estado=$row->Estado;
    $Quantidade=$row->Quantidade;
?>     
     <li>
        <a href="http://site.com.br/?page_id=22277&estado=<?=$ID;?>"><?=$Estado;?> <?=$Quantidade;?></a>
     </li>   
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa usar PHP "puro" dentro do WordPress. 
Ele tem as funções próprias pra esse tipo de coisa. 
Aconselho olhar o Codex. Pra ter mais detalhes sobre. 
Você vai precisar aprender sobre [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) do WordPress e só [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).
Você pode resolver isso de maneira muito mais simples. Por exemplo:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'estados', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<a href="?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?> </a>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

"Só isso" já vai trazer todos os estado cadastrados com seu nome por exemplo.
O WordPress é "quase um framework"...
Com isso você não precisa reinventar a roda.

Comment: O meu problema é que os dados estão tabelas separadas e preciso unir todos em uma unica seleção.

Comment: @HenriqueS.Santos, agora mesmo, o problema é que sua pergunta não tem detalhes suficientes... Que tabelas `treasuremap` são essas? Como são criadas? O que tem a ver com seu site? Tem um link "editar" justo abaixo da pergunta, pode modificar a vontade (desde que não mude o sentido original da pergunta).